# How to hide the tab headers in c#?

Tags: c#, combobox, tabs

I'm fresher to C#. I have a doubt, please anyone clarify me.

Firstly when i clicked on a button in first form, a new form should be opened with only one tab by default (basically this form will have 3 tabs).

In the default tab i will have a `comboBox` with list of 2 items. If i have selected a particular item, then the corresponding tab should be appeared beside 
the default tab.

I have done everything but i didn't get how to hide the tab other than the default one,and how to show the corresponding tab when an item was selected from combo box. please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A TabControl has multiple TabPages, each of them having a [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6e1ah1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

(assuming you are using WinForms)

Answer (score 0):

TabPage has no Visible Property, you have to remove the tab then add it again, here is a simple piece of code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<int> myList = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5 };
            listBox1.DataSource = myList;


            foreach (var item in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                MyTabPages.Add(item as TabPage);
            }

        }

        List<TabPage> MyTabPages = new List<TabPage>();


        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyTabPages.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            Int32 Index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            if (Index >= 0 && Index <= MyTabPages.Count - 1)
            {
                if(tabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(MyTabPages[Index]) < 0)
                {
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(MyTabPages[Index]);
                }
                else
                {
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(MyTabPages[Index]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right about the Visible property, but this code is not very good.  I'll post a counter example.

Answer (score 0):

These methods should help you:

```
public void ShowTab(TabControl tabs, TabPage page)
{
    tabs.TabPages.Add(page)
}

public void HideTab(TabControl tabs, TabPage page)
{
    tabs.TabPages.Remove(page)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example with a tab (tabPage1) as default tab with a comboBox control named comboBox1:

```
//Temporarly list to keep created tabs
List<TabPage> tempPages = new List<TabPage>(); 

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("tabPage2");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("tabPage3");
}

public void RemoveTabs()
{
    //Remove all tabs in tempPages if there are any
    if (tempPages != null)
    {
        foreach (var page in tempPages)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(page);
        }
        tempPages.Clear();
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        RemoveTabs();
        var newTabName = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
        var newtab = new TabPage(newTabName);
        //Create the new tabPage 
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newtab);
        //Add the newly created tab to the tempPages list
        tempPages.Add(newtab);
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah it was useful.Now how can i add buttons to those respective tab pages?

Comment: As you need to remove and add tabpages trough the code, u have to programmatic add the controls to it i suppose. But to be honest the things i think u would like to do, don't do it like this in winforms, u only making everything harder then it already is. Look for another infrastructure/setup. (However WPF supports showing and hiding tabpages with `Visibility.Collapsed`)